# bandit24 brute forcing program

Tags: code-golf

I was doing the bandit wargame from [overthewire.org](https://www.overthewire.org) and [because I am a script kiddie, I googled the answer for level 24.](https://medium.com/@lukmandenny/overthewire-wargames-bandit-walkthrough-0-34-3c6a52c5e436#2265)

```
password="UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ"
for i in {0000..9999} 
//looping to try any possible pin code
do
echo $password' '$i >> wordlist.txt 
//save password and possible pin code into wordlist 
done
```

I saw the bash script, and thought, "Well I couldn't have done that because I'm not good at bash." but then I realized that this problem could be done in other languages.

The challenge is simple.

1. Pipe the password in from stdin.
2. Append a space in-between the password and the pin or output it separately
3. Output all PIN combinations. Make sure that there are 4 digits outputted.
4. BONUS flush the output after each line. This is done automatically with `std::endl`.

I went ahead and did it in C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
        string key; //1
        getline(cin, key); //I heard that std::getline is
        //only standard for linux, so for practical
        //purposes use cin.getline(char*,size)
        for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){   //3
                cout << key << setfill('0') << ' ' //2
                << setw(4) << i << endl;  //4
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Obviously it can do better than 301 bytes, but you get the gist.

Also any language is acceptable as long as it can produce the same formatted strings separated by new lines or line breaks.

Comment: I would suggest removing rule 4. It doesn't add anything to the challenge, and anyway only makes sense for languages which have any notion of buffering/flushing output.

Comment: @Sanchises Actually it "makes sense" for every programs that prints to stdout on Linux, but I agree with the point.

Comment: May we use a comma as a delimiter, instead of a space?

Comment: I'm unsure why the I/O is restricted to STDIN when this could be taken as a command-line argument. Would you consider removing this restriction that is counter to the site's accepted defaults?

Comment: What does "or output it separately" mean in practice? (May we use multiple spaces? May we use any other consistent string of characters? May we use the password itself? May we output the password 10000 times and then the pins? ...)

Comment: If you don't put four characters the program won't work for bandit24. It says that there isn't enough data.

Comment: Also for the output it separately thing, I said that because you could just do
`key += " "` and not have to worry about it, but I chose to output it separately.

Comment: That doesn't answer @JonathanAllan's question of what "output it separately" means here. So, for that reason, I'm VTCing as unclear.

Comment: "as long as it can produce the same formatted strings separated by new lines or line breaks". Does this mean the output must be sorted, and sorted the same as your example code's output?

Comment: In fact, it doesn't have to be sorted. The numbers could be made recursively, like 1000 2000 or backwards from 9999.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>9</s> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
žh4ã€‚»
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L4Mk8OLHzWtedQw69Du//9D830jQ4rSipzcPCoDI3LTzdKrkksKHcv9c8sNPfMzogA)

**Explanation:**

```python
žh       # Push builtin string "0123456789"
  4ã     # Get the cartesian product of 4: ["0000","0001",...,"9998","9999"]
    €    # Map each string to:
     ‚   #  Pair it with the (implicit) input-string
      »  # Join each inner list by spaces, and then all strings by newlines
         # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 15 bytes

```
Ｅ×χφ⁺⁺θ ⭆◧Ｉι⁴Σλ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3sUAjJDM3tVjD0EBHwdDAwEBTRyEgp7RYA0wU6igoKSgBhYJLgMrTQaoDElN8UtNKNJwTi0s0MoFSJiDp0lyNHE0QsP7/PzTfNzKkKO2/blkOAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Test case uses shortened password to avoid TIO output limit. Explanation:

```
 ×χφ            Multiply predefined variables 10 with 1000
Ｅ               Map over implicit range
           ι    Current index
          Ｉ     Cast to string
         ◧  ⁴   Left-pad to width literal `4`
        ⭆    Σλ Convert non-digits to zeros
    ⁺⁺θ         Concatenate with the password and a space
                Implicitly output each entry on its own line
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 12 bytes

```
V^jkUT4++QdN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PywuKzs0xERbOzDF7/9/pdB838iQorQiJzePysCI3HSz9KrkkkLHcv/cckPP/IwopX/5BSWZ@XnF/3VTAA)

### Explanation

```
V^jkUT4++QdN
V             : For n in
 ^    4       : repeated cartesian product 4 times of
  jkUT        : "0123456789"
       ++QdN  : output input + ' ' + n
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 33 bytes

```matlab
@(a)fprintf([a,' %04u\n'],0:9999)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI1EzraAoM68kTSM6UUddQdXApDQmTz1Wx8DKEgg0/6dpqJekFpeoa/4HAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 32 bytes

```ruby
10000.times{|i|puts$_+" %04i"%i}
```

Suggested by Dingus.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/39AACPRKMnNTi6trMmsKSkuKVeK1lRRUDUwylVQza///D833jQwpSitycvOoDIzITTdLr0ouKXQs988tN/TMz4j6l19QkpmfV/xfNw8A)

```ruby
->a{(0..9999).to_a.map(&:to_s).map{|x|a+" "+x.rjust(4,"0")}.join("\n")};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvxfXFJkm55aUmzNlWb7X9cusVrDQE/PEgg09Ury4xP1chMLNNSsgMxiTRC7uqaiJlFbSUFJu0KvKKu0uETDREfJQEmzVi8rPzNPQykmD8i25vqvYmdjo5AWDTQ99n9ovm9kSFFakZObR2VgRG66WXpVckmhY7l/brmhZ35GFAA)

Comment: [32 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/39AACPRKMnNTi6trMmsKSkuKVeK1lRRUDUwylVQza///D833jQwpSitycvOoDIzITTdLr0ouKXQs988tN/TMz4j6l19QkpmfV/xfNw8A) with `-n` flag. Generally speaking you should try to avoid `to_a` and `to_s`. For instance, `(0..9999).to_a` can just be `[*0..9999]`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Takes input as a single element array. If we can use comma as the delimiter instead of space, the last 3 characters can be removed.

```
ïL²o ùT4)m¸
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=70yybyD5VDQpbbg&input=WyJhYmMiXQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), (8?) 10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sup>8 if we may output delimited by multiple spaces (replace `K€Y` with `G`).</sup>

```
ØDṗ4ɠ,ⱮK€Y
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/9qZWxsef//w5hE4bmXNMmgLOKxrkvigqxZ//94)**

#### How?

```
ØDṗ4ɠ,ⱮK€Y - Main Link: no arguments
ØD         - digit characters = "0123456789"
   4       - four
  ṗ        - Cartesian power -> list of all pins
    ɠ      - read a line from STDIN
      Ɱ    - map (across the pins) applying:
     ,     -   pair
       K€  - join each with a space character
         Y - join with newlines
           - implicit print
```